# What is the maximum length for Vimeo titles and descriptions?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm building a publishing service which uploads video files to Vimeo through it's API and I'd like to know the maximum length a video's title, description and tags could have.

I went through the documentation (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/responses/video) and https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#edit_video, but I couldn't find anything.

I presume, that there are some hard (although undocumented) limits, but couldn't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to upload a test video and edit it to be able to get this information:

- Maximum length for the title is **128 characters**.
- Maximum length for the description is **5000 characters**.
- Tags could be the same as title (there was no limit in the validation)

I assume, that the same constraints apply to the API part as well.